# Qt brother window refresh causes efficiency

Tags: qt, qwidget, qopenglwidget

I have a parent window that has a `QStackedLayout` layout, using `QStackedLayout::All` mode, with a `QOpenGlWidget` at the bottom to render the video.

The top layer is a custom `QWidget C` that rewrites the mouse event.

When the mouse moves, will update to update the interface, specify the update area?

Such as update (QRect (0,0,20,30)), but when the underlying QOpenGlWidget calls update () (no specified refresh area, the default is the entire Widget) to refresh Interface, I get the Rect from C's paintEvent is not QRect (0,0,20,30), but the whole width and height of C, is there any way to solve it?

[this is parent Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWVWf.png)
[this is a Contanier, it have a customwidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3N4E.png)
[this is Container, pWidget in the previous image, The red part is customWidget C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqtUu.png)
[this is customWidget C, override mouse events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsb22.png)
[customWidget C, override paintEvent to draw Graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weaoI.png)

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Yes, of course@Alexander Chernin

Comment: that is all key code,If you have any findings, please feel free to suggest me.@Alexander Chernin